# wht does jQuery also append code to the end of an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Can anyone tell my what this is that jquery has added to the end of my output to "posts-container" and how to fix it? Its not coming from the json so what is the issue. code is below and the output is adding at the end.

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#waiting').show(500);
        $('#message').hide(0);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://domain.com/api/index.php/id/18271',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'apiKeytest=1',
            success: function(r){
                var output = '';
                for (a in r.DATA) {
                    for (b in r.DATA[a]) {
                        if (typeof(r.DATA[a][b]) == 'object') {
                            for (c in r.DATA[a][b]) {
                                output += c + ' = ' + r.DATA[a][b][c] + '<br />';
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            output += b + ' = ' + r.DATA[a][b] + '<br />';
                        }
                    }
                }
                jQuery('#posts-container').append(output);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $('#waiting').hide(500);
                $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error').text('There was an error.').show(500);

            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

output has this at the end

```
argumentNames = function () { var names = this.toString().match(/^[\s\(]*function[^(]*\((.*?)\)/)[1].split(",").invoke("strip"); return names.length == 1 && !names[0] ? [] : names; }
bindAsEventListener = function () { var __method = this, args = $A(arguments), object = args.shift(); return function (event) {return __method.apply(object, [event || window.event].concat(args));}; }
curry = function () { if (!arguments.length) { return this; } var __method = this, args = $A(arguments); return function () {return __method.apply(this, args.concat($A(arguments)));}; }
delay = function () { var __method = this, args = $A(arguments), timeout = args.shift() * 1000; return window.setTimeout(function () {return __method.apply(__method, args);}, timeout); } etc............
```

the json

```
{
    "ERRORS": [],
    "DATA": [
        {
            "itemActive": true,
            "itemTxt": "test",
            "itemID": "30d2f2c1-58ca-4b3d-b3e0-d284ae5b25ab",
            "itemValidTo": "October, 19 2011 00:00:00",
            "itemName": "test",
            "itemCreated": "October, 03 2011 00:00:00",
            "image": {
                "imageCreated": "October, 05 2011 00:00:00",
                "imageURL": "test.jpg",
                "imageID": "bc869a94-fee5-4fc8-bd21-e2de2f020310"
            },
            "itembio": 53.0650849
        }
    ],
    "MESSAGES": [
        {
            "TOTAL": 1,
            "CURRENTPAGE": 1,
            "TOTALPAGES": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.forinloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

So you are probably using some library or maybe your own code extends the native object.

Witch is the functions that appears in the output. (toString of a function gives you its code)

You can get around it by checking if the property is from the object or its prototype with this call.

```
 if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   // you have a property from the object
 }
```